# RDLC Cover Page?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportviewer, rdlc

I'm working on a system that is going to have multiple reports (each with their own RDLC file). I would also like these reports to have a common Cover Report. My thoughts for this would be:

1. Create a CoverReport.rdlc
2. For each actual report, start with a Subreport that points to the CoverReport.rdlc.

Is this an acceptable solution, or is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself the headache and navigate / [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159088%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to the other reports.  Subreports are great *sometimes*.  I would suggest having the same header and footer on the reports.

Comment: Thanks, but to my understanding a link would require the user to click it, where a subreport is displayed inline. For a cover page, I would require the latter.